# Usage of word "Former"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it fine to use the word "former" when pertaining to an object?

Example:

- John's former laptop.

Comment: I would say "John's old laptop".

Comment: As the answers apparently indicate, it is technically correct to use *former* but some people don't like doing so. So, there's a difference of opinion between the grammar and its stylistic use.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it fine to use the word "former" when pertaining to an **object**?
>   e.g. John's former laptop.

No, not really unless you were mocking either yourself or "John". That example sentence seems to suggest that John had a strong, perhaps emotional, attachment to his laptop. Perhaps if that sentence was part of a longer passage, it would sound acceptable. I can see someone resorting to "former" if they wanted to use a synonym for "old", "previous", "prior" or even "ex".

You can talk about a *former line* of laptops, and *a former name* of a laptop (or cell phone) but generally speaking, I would just say "old", as in “John's old laptop.” Context will tell readers if the laptop is dated or if it has been replaced.

Oxford Living Dictionaries's second definition of *[old](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/old)* is

> 2. [attributive] Belonging to the past; former.
>
>    - ‘Today's feelings were sparked by me walking past my old primary school yesterday for the first time in ages.’

We tend to use *former* for people, e.g. *the former President of the US*, *his former wife*, *the former leader of the Conservative Party*.

Comment: A little bit confusing with the other answer. Hmm

Comment: @Jonjie Take your pick :) or just wait until someone posts a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adjective 'former' can be used both with things and people.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/former):

***former***

adjective

1a: coming before in time

// She now appears like her former self.

b: of, relating to, or occurring in the past

//former correspondence
 //restoring the theater to its former glory.

Comment: Please add > before quoting a definition, this helps users see which words are your own and which belong to the dictionary. An actual link would be nice, too.

Comment: A little bit confusing with the other answers. Hmm

Answer (score 0):

'Former laptop' is not obviously incorrect, but it does sound somewhat awkward (which is probably what prompted the question, and which is confirmed by Mari-Lou A). The awkwardness is, however, not due to the fact that a laptop is not a person, as there is nothing that limits the use of *former* to persons.

In the phrases such as *the former President* or *his former wife*, which seem analogous to the one that is under discussion here, the word *former* is used for a former **occupant of a particular role**, i.e. for a former occupant of a particular position in some institutional framework. In these contexts, there is a conceptual distinction between the role and its occupant. Because of its similarity with such phrases, *John's former laptop* leaves an impression that the speaker thinks of *one's laptop* as a role in some institutional framework, that is conceptually distinct from the physical machine that occupies it. We normally, however, do not think of laptops that way, and this is what makes the phrase *John's former laptop* sound awkward, outside a special context.

There may, however, be contexts in which *one's laptop* is thought of as a role distinct from the machine that occupies the role, and to which the phrase *John's former laptop* may be well suited. Suppose that an employer issues to each employee exactly one laptop, to be used for employment-related purposes, and that the machines issued that way are, from time to time, replaced by different ones. In such a context, *John's laptop* may stand for the officially issued machine, and not merely for some laptop that John happens to possess. If we are in a context in which laptops are thought of and spoken that way, then *John's former laptop* may well be an apt phrase for a machine that previously occupied that role in John's employment, but that has since then been withdrawn by the employer.